# Makefile debug basic without execution

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Is it possible to get the same output of `make --debug=basic`
without the compiling commands to be executed?

I would like to get the same behaviour of a `make --just-print`
but with `make --debug=basic`'s output.

Comment: `make` has no idea which commands are "compiling commands"; so without extensive cooperation from the author of your `Makefile`, no.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the question, but does `make --debug=basic --just-print` not do exactly what you want?

Comment: You are completely right @Beta! Thank you, this is what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @Beta's comment: `make --debug=basic --just-print` does the job.