# Is it possible to dump Kbuild?

Tags: linux, makefile, linux-kernel, gnu-make, kbuild

I would like to know if it is possible -- and how -- to dump all Kbuild
targets in the Linux Kernel.

I want to get all targets to run given a .config.

Thank you

Comment: I think I tried `make -n` once, but it didn't work very well for the Linux kernel.

Comment: It is quite related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66102567/makefile-debug-basic-without-execution/66103691#66103691). Ideed, it does not work very well for the Kernel: it seems that even if you want to just print it, it still needs some files to be generated to go till the end.